# failing to locate fortran

Tags: macos, fortran

I have successfully configured a fortran program and I am now trying to install, but am having some errors and not sure how to resolve them. I am totally new to fortran and Linux

This is the error message

```
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in Main
Making install in mpplib
 mpifort -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.7.0/external -I/usr/local/include      -I/usr/local/include  -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.7.0/Share -O3 -finline-  functions -fconvert=big-endian -fno-range-check -fPIC -c mod_mppparam.F90
/Users/mada0007/anaconda3/envs/Research_ass/bin/mpifort: line 373: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-   gfortran: command not found
make[2]: *** [mod_mppparam.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: You apparently have installed MPI but not gfortran. You need to install it with conda: `conda install gfortran`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that gfortran is not installed on your system. You can go to your operating system's software package installation program and it might be called something like `gfortran` or `gcc-gfortran` (you will probably have to type the superuser root password). Or because you are using conda you can install it using with `conda install gfortran`. If you do it with conda then you will only get to use it when you have activated your conda but if you install it on the operating system then you will have it available all of the time.

`mpifort` is a program that you use to compile fortran programs for parallel processing. But it is not a fortran compiler itself---it must find an actual fortran compiler "under the bonnet", as they say. Which can be one of several options, so for example you might have one of the commercial fortran compilers installed on your system and it will find it and use it as an alternative to gfortran. The problem which you have at the moment is that it is not finding any at all.

Comment: thaks after installing fortran, now in get this error      Fatal Error: File 'mod_intkinds.mod' opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file. What could be wrong this time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **macOS** (which is not **Linux** by the way), you should probably be using **homebrew** as your package manager. Get it at [brew.sh](https://brew.sh)

Then `gfortran` is part of GCC (*"GNU Compiler Collection"*), so you will need:

```
brew install gcc
```

Then you need to make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH because that's where **homebrew** installs everything. Ideally you would put the following in your login profile so it gets run every time you login, but you can type it in the Terminal instead before trying to use `gfortran`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Check it is installed and working with:

```
gfortran -v
```

Output will be along these lines:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/9.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin19 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0/lib/gcc/9 --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 9.3.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-multilib --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/include --with-sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0)
```

Comment: Thank for your comment. After install fortran same process as you did, I get this error now when I try to:::make install        'Fatal Error: File 'mod_intkinds.mod' opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file' what is wrong now ?

Comment: I can't actually see what you are trying to compile, nor how. My guess is that you should run `make clean` to clean up old, failed builds, then try `make` again.

Comment: @ Mark I am trying to install RegCM climate model and I just tried make install with this same error                 mpifort -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/external -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/Users/mada0007/Documents/softwares/RegCM-4.6.1/Share -O3 -fconvert=big-endian -fno-range-check -fPIC -c mod_mppparam.F90
mod_mppparam.F90:22.6:

  use mod_intkinds
      1
Fatal Error: File 'mod_intkinds.mod' opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file